# What is the triggering level of INTR interrupt?

Tags: interrupts, microprocessor, 8085

In the book we are told about the triggering level of other interrupts but I could not found any statements about the triggering level of INTR.please answer.

Comment: The first place to start is by reading the datasheet of whatever processor or microcontroller that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

a quick google search reveals that the interrupt level for INTR in 8085 is level 5 [image]

Please do your research before asking a question! Hope that helps! check this document for more info: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/108107029/module8/lecture2/lecture2.pdf